# connect laptop to TV: Toshiba notebook connect ton LCD tv

Tags: laptop, tv

When I connect yellow / white / red cable from my toshiba a45-s250 notebook to my lcd sharp tv 1080 p. the image is very blurry. is there a way to connect so that image on tv would be clear and normal ??

Comment: my notebook appears to have svideo output. So is there a way to connect it to lcd tv with 1080p ?

Comment: my tv appears to have hdmi inputs so can i connect my laptop to TV through hdmi inputs?

Answer (score 1):

Run an HDMI cable directly from your laptop's HDMI port to your TV; simplest, and best solution for TVs like that.

They look like this:

[image]

Comment: The toshiba a45-s250 model doesn't have any HDMI connector.

Answer (score 0):

Both the yellow/red/white cables and svideo are analog outputs, and low resolution.  You will never get a decent picture from them.  If your laptop has a DVI output, you can convert that to HDMI with a cheap adaptor ([this](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10419&cs_id=1041902&p_id=2029&seq=1&format=2), for example).  They are actually the same digital format, just with a different connector (and HDMI can also carry audio).  It depends on the video card, but it should be able to do 1080p.